# Swift: For Loop End Condition Evaluated Only Once?

Tags: swift, loops, for-loop, appkit, foundation

I am attempting to understand how Swift handles for-in loops.

**Overview**: we are iterating over the rows of an `NSOutlineView`. If a condition is met, we expand the item, which obviously changes the overall row count of the outlineView.

**Pre-Condition**: the OutlineView has 5 "root" items. Each of those has 5 child items.

---

## Example

```
final class anOutlineView: NSOutlineView
{
    override func reloadData()
    {
        super.reloadData()
        
        for i in 0 ..< self.numberOfRows
        {
            // Assume we expand the item at row 0, which increases 
            // the overall outlineView row count from 5 to 10.
        }
    }
}
```

In this approach, the loop stops when `i == 4`. I assume that's because Swift evaluates the range only once, the first time it encounters it? Is there a way to change that behavior so that the conditions are re-evaluated each time through the loop, like a traditional `for` loop?

Replacing the `for` loop with a `while` loop obviously works and is a fine solution. I'm simply trying to understand the nuances of Swift because this behavior is not what I expected. In Objective-C, the `for` loop conditions were evaluated on each iteration and it was a well-known performance optimization to refrain from calling `self.property` in loop conditions (unless a good reason existed, as it does in this case.)

Comment: The `for-in` loop in Swift to me feels like `foreach` in C#, where you are not supposed to change the collection you're iterating over. Here the matter is the condition (which indeed only gets evaluated once, but the real problem has been pointed out in Martin R's answer), but it's the same thing because you're indirectly modifying the collection: if you were iterating over an array and removing items from it, it would crash badly at some point, because you would be trying to access stuff outside of the new bounds.

Comment: @Joakim: that's precisely what the loop is for.

Comment: @s.m. it does not crash in ObjC because we explicitly get the new number of rows in each loop iteration. It would certainly crash if you cached that value before the loop body and used it throughout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0 ..< self.numberOfRows` is a `Range` and in particular a `Sequence`. Iterating over a sequence is done by creating an iterator, and then calling its `next()` method until the iterator is exhausted, compare [`IteratorProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/iteratorprotocol):

> Whenever you use a for-in loop with an array, set, or any other collection or sequence, you’re using that type’s iterator. Swift uses a sequence’s or collection’s iterator internally to enable the for-in loop language construct.

So

```
for i in 0 ..< self.numberOfRows {
    ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
let range = 0 ..< self.numberOfRows
var it = range.makeIterator()
while let i = it.next() {
    ...
}
```

Modifying `numberOfRows` during the iteration does not mutate the range (which is a value type) or the iterator, and therefore does not affect the number of iterations.

Comment: Interesting. So Swift is essentially enforcing the performance optimization that was previously left to the developer to know. It's not wrong; it's just different than C-style languages where you can count on the for loop conditions being reevaluated for each iteration.